# Regarding Eclispe EMF Command Frame WorK

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-emf

Can any one tell me how to use `AddCommand` rather than `SetCommand" to do the following.

I have a class like this:

```
class Profile {
    List achievements;
    List grades;
    List extracurrics;
}
```

Now, suppose I need to add a grade object to this Profile object,how can I achieve this by using `AddCommand` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
Profile p = ...;
Grade g = ...;
Command add = AddCommand.create(domain,p, YourProfilePackage.Literals.PROFILE__GRADES, Collections.singleton(g));
```

where YourProfilePackage should be in the code generated automatically from your EMF model.

Answer (score 2):

SetCommand is basically used to set values in EMF model, and AddCommand is used to modify collection values inside EMF model, so in general it should not be a problem to use AddCommand.

You can create new AddCommand using static creation function in AddCommand:

```
AddCommand.create(EditingDomain domain, EObject owner, EStructuralFeature feature, java.lang.Object value)
```

Explanation of given values:

```
domain: the editing domain your model lives in
owner: element you are doing the modifications to
feature: feature in model, that should be given to you by the EPackage of your model.
         So this case is the Grades list feature
value: the new object you add to the list
```

There are many different create helpers in add command, so if you need to define index to list, it is also doable.

I don't have EMF running here, so I cannot provide any direct sources, but let me know if that didn't do the trick.